# Serialize a string with pyyaml without an ellipsis

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to use `yaml.dump` with pyyaml to convert a string into something that is yaml safe (i.e., all things that need to be escaped are properly escaped). I will then insert these strings into a large yaml document.

The issue is that `yaml.dump` wants to treat the string as the whole document, and add `...` (end of document), like

```
In [4]: yaml.dump("a string")
Out[4]: 'a string\n...\n'
```

How do I get it to not add the `\n...\n`, short of just manually removing it? Or is there a better way to quote a string for yaml consumption using pyyaml?

Comment: any reason why constructing python data first and dumping to yaml in the end would not work for you?

Comment: I'm constructing a human-readable yaml document with comments.

Answer (score 6):

Providing a [`default_style`](https://dpinte.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/pyaml-dump-option/) argument appears to help to some extent:

```
>>> yaml.dump("a string", default_style='"')
'"a string"\n'
```

There's also a `line_break` argument, but while it works for *changing* the terminating newline:

```
>>> yaml.dump("a string", default_style='"', line_break="\r")
'"a string"\r'
```

... it doesn't appear capable of *removing* it:

```
>>> yaml.dump("a string", default_style='"', line_break="")
'"a string"\n'
>>> yaml.dump("a string", default_style='"', line_break=None)
'"a string"\n'
>>> yaml.dump("a string", default_style='"', line_break=False)
'"a string"\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add something to a yaml document that contains comments, you should look at [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (of which I am the author). It is a enhancement of PyYAML, that preserves comments in the YAML file.

That way if you want to add something to the sequence in this `input.yml` file:

```
- alpha   # first one
- beta    # another one
```

you can just do:

```
# coding: utf-8

import ruamel.yaml

file_name = 'input.yml'

config = ruamel.yaml.load(open(file_name), ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
config.append('ω')

ruamel.yaml.dump(config, open('output.yml', 'w'),
                 Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
ruamel.yaml.dump(config, open('unicode.yml', 'w'), allow_unicode=True,
                 Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

and get in `output.yml` (with what I think you call proper escaping):

```
- alpha   # first one
- beta    # another one
- "\u03C9"
```

and `unicode.yml`:

```
- alpha   # first one
- beta    # another one
- ω
```

Please note that the comments are preserved, something e.g. PyYAML doesn't do.
Adding a comment to the appended element is possible as well.

Comment: Oh my God! Did someone finally write a round-tripping yaml parser for Python? I'm definitely going to check this out.

Comment: @asmeurer Yes someone finally did ;-). A few months ago actually, I only now got around to go over the pyyaml tag on [so] and see if some answers could be added or existing ones benefited from that. If there is something not working, please report a bug (with an example) on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml)